# Passing vars in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a jquery function, but i have a problem passing some vars to my function.
This is what i am tring to do, i resumed my code below:

```
var func = "appendTo";
var myid = "thisismyid";
var element = "div";
$("<"+element+"/>"{if(myid != ''){ id:myid}}).func($elem);
```

There's a way to do that?
This is the only working code that i can get:

```
$("<"+element+"/>").appendTo($elem);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$("<"+element+"/>"), { id: myid ? myid : null})[func]($elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter when creating an element is an object. You cannot break an object with an if statement. You can however use a ternary to achieve the same results:

```
var func = "appendTo";
var myid = "thisismyid";
var element = "div";
$("<"+element+"/>", {id: (myid != '' ? myid : '') }).func($elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the code using the following:

```
$("<"+element+"/>",{id: (myid != '' ? myid : '')})[func]($elem);
```